# SQL select conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a table that contains data in the following structure:

```
Id | OperationType | ObjectName | dt_created
-- | ------------- | ---------- | ----------
1  | 4             | test.com   |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
2  | 7             | test.com   |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
3  | 17            | test.com   |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
4  | 26            | test.com   |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
5  | 8             | test.com   |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
6  | 4             | test.com   |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
7  | 17            | 123.com    |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
8  | 18            | 123.com    |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
9  | 26            | 123.com    |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
10 | 8             | 123.com    |  2015-08-30 23:23:57.000
```

I want to get the ID's of the records where there is an operation type **17** followed by **26**

I have tried a few approaches like:

```
select abc.id, abc.PreviousOperationType
from (select id,
       case 
            when OperationType = 26
            then 
                lead(OperationType, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by id)
            else 
                null 
            end as PreviousOperationType
from operation
where dt_created between '2015-09-20' and '2015-09-30') as abc
where abc.PreviousOperationType is not null and abc.PreviousOperationType= 17
```

but not able to get accurate results.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,
J

Comment: Show us the expected result as well.

Comment: which sql server you are using

Comment: You want Id 3 or 4 in result ?

Comment: Seeing that `dt_created` contains a time, you may not want to use `between`, but rather something like `where dt_created >= '2015-09-20' and dt_created < '2015-10-01'`, so as not to only get the first second of the last day specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query gives you ID 3, because it is of type 17 and is followed by a record of type 26.

```
select id
from
(
  select 
    id,
    operationtype,
    lead(operationtype) over (order by dt_created) as next_operationtype
  from operation
) op
where operationtype = 17 and next_operationtype = 26;
```

Comment: Darn it, sagi beat me to it ;-)

Comment: figured it: I had to use a partition by ObjectName while ordering by dt_created.

Answer (score 3):

You were close :

```
select abc.id, abc.PreviousOperationType
from (select id,
             OperationType,
             lead(OperationType, 1, 0) over (order by id) NextOperationType
        from operation
        where dt_created between '2015-09-20' and '2015-09-30') abc
where abc.OperationType = 17 AND 
      abc.NextOperationType= 26
```

No need to use the partition by clause inside the `LEAD()` function, since every ID is unique .

Answer (score 1):

Just using ROW_NUMBER() function without the Lead() function , hence compatible with sql server 2008 and 2005 too :)

```
;WITH X AS (
Select * 
       ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) rn
from TableName )
SELECT x.*
FROM X x
INNER JOIN X y ON x.rn + 1 = y.rn 
              AND x.OperationType = 17
              AND y.OperationType = 26
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guys, all the comments helped. Atleast I was able to identify the gap in my understanding of the issue. I need to fetch records where 17 is immediately preceded by 26 pivoting around the Object Name, so for each ObjectName. I have updated the table structure. So, I need records 3 and 4 only if the table data looks like the one in the post. Thanks